# How do I print a tkinter button for every entry in a list and make the command correspond to that list entry?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am unable to figure out how to make a button appear and also make it do the right thing. O have been trying all sorts of ways to make a button for every entry in my list playlist and make it play the sound when pressed. Right now it prints a button for every line, which is good, but it doesn't make the right sound play. Every button that is added plays the sound that the last button placed should make.

```
import pygame
from pygame.mixer import stop
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Ricky's Epic Sound Collection")
root.geometry("720x550")

def playmusic(filename):
    pygame.init()
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(filename)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(0)

freek = tk.Text(root, height=5, width=20)
freek.pack()

filepathfiller= tk.Button(root, text="voeg geluid toe aan library", command=lambda: zandkasteel())
filepathfiller.pack()

printButton = tk.Button(root, text="maak knoppen aan", command=lambda: button_placer())
printButton.pack()

def zandkasteel(): #creates a textfile with filepaths to the sounds
    input_a = freek.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    print(f'{input_a=}')
    with open ("sounds.txt", "a") as sound:
        sound.write(input_a)
        sound.write("\n")



def button_placer(): #creates buttons for every item in the list created by reading Sounds.txt
    fragmenten = open("sounds.txt", "r")
    playlist = fragmenten.readlines()
    print(playlist)
    for item in playlist:
        button = tk.Button(root,text=item,command=lambda:playmusic(item.strip('\n')))
        button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If anyone knows of a solution, please do share.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having had a similar issue when dynamically creating buttons. I think it might come from item.strip('\n') not being executed at the time of declaring the button. This would mean, that the anonymous function will only hold a soft copy of item, which will finally take the value of the last entry in playlist.
If I understand correctly, item.strip('\n') will create a string, right?
Try saving that string to a variable in the for loop and then passing that variable to playmusic in the lambda function declaration:

```
for item in playlist:
    song = item.strip('\n')
    button = tk.Button(root, text=item, command=lambda: playmusic(song))
    button.pack()
```